# Is spring data jpa tightly coupled with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, eclipselink

I just read spring in action and I read about spring data jpa. As I know jpa is only interface and it cannot be used without implementation. I noticed that spring data jpa use only the hibernate library as ORM. Is it tightly coupled with hibernate or I can change the implementation of jpa with something else like eclipselink for example?

Also I am using Spring boot - is there any way to integrate eclipselink without spring data in spring boot?

Comment: Google search with "spring data eclipselink" results me to this [first result](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/eclipselink)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data JPA builds only on the JPA specification. You can use it with any implementation you like.

As for the second question: Yes you can use Spring Boot without Spring Data. And you can use normal Spring Configurations to configure whatever you want, including JPA.